# It is possible to get a list of parameters in a post action with asp.net mvc

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have a for to update a list of entities it is possible to do something like these

```
<%using (Html.BeginForm())
  {
%>

<% foreach (var entity in Model)
   {
%>
<p>
    <%= Html.TextBox("Entity.Name", entity.Name) %>
</p>
<% } %>
    <input type="submit" value="Update" />
<% } %>
```

and then in the action receive a list of entities? or a list of names...
I don't want to create a form for each entity with his own button, i want to update all the entities toghether.
Wich options i have to do these?

Thanks in advance,

Alfredo

Comment: try not to use the name "name" for your columns in the database, use the entity for it aswell, like "Categoryname, Productname" etc. Else it gets very confusing as your application grows

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<%= Html.TextBox("name", entity.Name) %>

public ActionResult foo(string[] name)
```

or

```
<%= Html.TextBox("Entity["+index+"].Name", entity.Name) %>

//will create list of entities from form values
public ActionResult foo(IList<Entity> entity)
```

Process in Asp.Net Mvc terminology is called model binding.

[This](http://odetocode.com/Blogs/scott/archive/2009/04/27/12788.aspx) article might be worth checking out. And [another one](http://haacked.com/archive/2008/10/23/model-binding-to-a-list.aspx) about binding lists.